# transferir espaços vazios da base de dados para a última coluna no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde

Para me ajudar no problema estruturei uma base de dados fictícia

```
dados1<-c(15,15,16,17,18,52,48,47,65,32,'',15,14)
dados2<-c(15,15,16,17,18,52,'',47,65,32,15,15,14)
dados3<-rbind(dados1,dados2)
dados3<-data.frame(dados3)
```

onde o resultado de dados3 é o seguinte

```
         X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13
  dados1 15 15 16 17 18 52 48 47 65  32      15  14
  dados2 15 15 16 17 18 52    47 65  32  15  15  14
```

preciso transferir os espaços vazios para a última coluna, ou seja unir a base, deixando espaços vazios na última coluna

Comment: eu passaria cada linha para um vetor, excluiria o vetor vazio, e empilharia novamente. Mas é uma solução bem ingênua. Se ninguém responder em 1 semana, me mande um aviso aqui, que eu tento

Comment: Os espaços vazios podem ser interpretados como `NA`? Se primeiro espaço vazio (X7, dados2) for para a última coluna, quem deverá ocupar aquele *slot*? Descreva um pouco mais sobre as restrições do problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta solução parte do princípio que os dados deveriam ser numéricos mas que com o valor `''` passaram a ser carateres ou fatores.
Então, primeiro transformam-se em numéricos, o que faz os `''` ficarem `NA`.

```
dados3[] <- lapply(dados3, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Agora, vou trabalhar com uma cópia. No seu caso pode mudar isto e a instrução `apply`.

```
dados3b <- dados3
dados3b <- t(apply(dados3b, 1, function(x){
  if(anyNA(x)){
    n <- length(x)
    na <- which(is.na(x[-n]))
    for(i in na){
      x[i:(n - 1)] <- x[(i + 1):n]
      is.na(x) <- n
    }
  }
  x
}))

dados3b <- as.data.frame(dados3b)
dados3b
#        X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13
#dados1  15 15 16 17 18 52 48 47 65  32  15  14  NA
#dados2  15 15 16 17 18 52 47 65 32  15  15  14  NA
#dados2a 15 15 16 17 18 52 47 65 32  15  15  14  NA
```

**Dados.**

Para testar o código acima criei mais um vetor, com `''` na última posição.

```
dados1 <- c(15,15,16,17,18,52,48,47,65,32,'',15,14)
dados2 <- c(15,15,16,17,18,52,'',47,65,32,15,15,14)
dados2a <- c(15,15,16,17,18,52,47,65,32,15,15,14,'')
dados3 <- rbind(dados1, dados2, dados2a)
dados3 <- data.frame(dados3)
```